# Possibility to create a complexe order by with parameter

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

Into a Springboot app, I am trying to display a list of books with user pinned ones first. I am trying to make this `order by` in a already existing paginated specification

I have book and user entity where :

- A user can pin multiple books
- A book can be pinned by multiple users

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class BookEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(name = "user_has_book_pinned", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<UserEntity> userPinningBook = new HashSet<>();

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(name = "user_has_book_pinned", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<BookEntity> bookPinned = new HashSet<>();
}
```

### Attempt 1: Use of group by with an equal

```java
public static Specification<BookEntity> orderByPinned(long userId) {
    return new Specification<BookEntity>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<BookEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
            query.distinct(true);

            Order pinnedEventOrder = criteriaBuilder.desc(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.join("userPinningBook").get("id"), userId));
            query.orderBy(pinnedEventOrder);

            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

Where userId should be replaced with the current user id.

The problem here is that equal can not be used with a `order by` like this...

### Attempt 2: Use of another SELECT with LEFT JOIN

```sql
SELECT book.*, pinned.user_id FROM book
LEFT JOIN user_has_book_pinned pinned ON book.id = pinned.event_id AND pinned.user_id = CURRENT_USER
ORDER BY pinned.user_id DESC;
```

Where `CURRENT_USER` should be replaced with the current user id.

Like this, we create a new entity that has book information and pinned information.

Do I need to create a new entity ?
How can I use this into the Book Specification ?

### Attempt 3: Use of @Formula with previous select

```java
@Formula("(select (case WHEN count(*) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END) from book b JOIN b.userPinningBook userPinningBook where userPinningBook.book_id = id AND userPinningBook.user_id = CURRENT_USER_ID)")
private boolean isPinned;
```

Where CURRENT_USER should be replaced with the current user id.

The problem is that we can not do formula with parameters, so I can not change CURRENT_USER_ID **into a specification** to get the good order

### Is there any solution to put pinned books in top of other books ??

Comment: Do you also need list of users who has pinned the book? As in the example, you've selected `pinned.user_id`

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPQL like below in `JpaRepository<BookEntity,Long>`

```
@Query("SELECT book from BookEntity book " +
            "LEFT JOIN FETCH book.userPinningBook " +
            "WHERE book.userPinningBook.id= :id " +
            "ORDER BY book.userPinningBook.userId DESC")
List<BookEntity> findByUserPinningBookUserId(@Param("id") long id);
```

Comment: This do not make possible to use specification. I need to have the request paginated